# Transform "100K" string into 100000 int in Python

Tags: python

The function format_number is actually taking an int and removing dot and zero. But when I grab the info,  the input parameter can also be a string "30K" (for 30000) or "2M" (for 2000000) and I'd like the function to analyse the string, if its not a number, convert 30K into an int 30000 and do the rest, else just do the rest.

Can some help me I'm new in Python.

Here is my function :

```
def format_number(number):
    """
    Format number. Remove the unused comma. Replace the concatenation with
    relevant zeros. Remove the dot.

    :param number: str

    :return: int
    """
    formatted_num = number.replace(",", "")
    formatted_num = re.sub(
        r"(k)$", "00" if "." in formatted_num else "000", formatted_num
    )
    formatted_num = re.sub(
        r"(m)$", "00000" if "." in formatted_num else "000000", formatted_num
    )
    formatted_num = formatted_num.replace(".", "")
    return int(formatted_num)
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Your regexp looks for `k` and `m`, not `K` and `M`. Use `flags=re.I` to make it case-insensitive. There's also no need for the capture groups.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with `.`. Why do you replace with 1 less `0` when there's a `.` in the number?

Comment: This isn't formatting the number, it's doing the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, you need to match in a case-insensitive manner. You might also use a lambda with `re.sub` to handle both thousands and millions in one call.

```
re.sub(
  r"(k|m)$", 
  lambda m: "000" if m.group(1).lower() == 'k' else '000000', 
  "30k", 
  re.I
)
# => '30000'
```